# how to call a function into a php page

Tags: php, mysql

I have this function in my functions.php I have a php page called crimes how would I call this function in crimes.php.

```
function jailMe($script, $reason, $unbustable = false){

 global $fetch;

 if($unbustable == false){ $unbustable = "0"; }else{ $unbustable = "1"; }

if($script == 'Crime'){
$chanceToJail = rand(1,5);
if($chanceToJail == 2){
  $jailTime = time() + (rand(60,90));
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `jail` (`name`, `release`, `reason`, `bustable`) VALUES ('{$fetch['name']}','$jailTime','$reason','$unbustable')");
  return "<br /><br /><h1>You have been thrown into jail!</h1>";
}
```

crimes.php

```
session_start();
include_once("../src/connect.php");
include_once("../src/functions.php");

if($_POST['DoCrime']){
$Crime = (int)makesafe($_POST['DoCrime']);

if($Crime == '1'){
$NewRankXP = rand(1,15);
$NewMoney = rand(30,100);
$CrimeTime = (time()+ 60*1);

  mysql_query("UPDATE `Users` SET `RankXP` = `RankXP` + '$NewRankXP' WHERE `id` = '{$fetchChar['id']}'");
  mysql_query("UPDATE `Users` SET `Money` = `Money` + '$NewMoney' WHERE `id` = '{$fetchChar['id']}'");
  mysql_query("UPDATE `Users` SET `last_crime` = '$CrimeTime' WHERE `id` = '{$fetchChar['id']}'");
  echo "<font color='lime'>Success You got away with $NewRankXP XP and $$NewMoney!</font>";
}
}
```

Comment: Er... `<?php jailMe(/* args */); ?>`?

Answer (score 2):

Include the file and run the function ?

```
include_once('functions.php')

jailMe('some_script', 'hacking', true);
```

Comment: Yes I wish to run the function.

Comment: "doesn't work" is the most pointless comment. no one can help you with out a full explination

Comment: Unless your using a framework, an autoloader or something else that loads the files for you, you first have to include the file, and that requires the correct path and filename, which is impossible for us to tell you what is, only you know the filestructure you are working with. Once the file is properly included, and the function is available in the right scope etc. all you have to do is call the function with the parameters you need. Again, I have no idea how your file is built up, if the function is available, what the parameters should be etc ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to include the page with the function in it:

include_once('functions.php')

Then you can call the function:
jailMe('some_script', 'hacking', true);

If it doesn't work then you may need to make sure you have included the correct location of the file in the include statement.

You can test if the include has worked by putting an 'echo' at the top of the include just to test that the file is being located. If its not you need to put the correct location.

Comment: Yeah its going to the right file just function isn't working.